# how to detect click on a listview and send data to another activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, send

basically I want to make sure that as soon as a user clicks on a listview this sends a url to a youtube video to another activity to show with youtube api.

I would also like to know how to send a link to another activity

seen that there are at least a dozen links to insert I would not know how to do.

FIRST ACTIVITY

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.episodi_activity);

    //rimozione action bar

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
            getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
                }

        String[] titoli = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Titoli");

        ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

        List<ViewModel> models = new ArrayList<ViewModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titoli.length; i++) {
            String name = titoli[i];

            ViewModel model = new ViewModel(name);
            models.add(model);
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<ViewModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ViewModel>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, models);

        final String[] values = new String[] { "Gnu94B6Edrs", "PUTenLr0vpI"};

        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
        mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent video = new Intent(EpisodiActivity.this,VideoActivity.class);

                video.putExtra("tagLink", values[position]);
                startActivity(video);
            }
        });
```

SECOND ACTIVITY

```
public class VideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyBR-QH8hCO8U_WE_sIPGhEQIGmBEYCi7pQ";
private String VIDEO;



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.videoactivity);
          YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)
                  findViewById(R.id.youtube_video);
       youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

       Bundle VIDEO = getIntent().getExtras();
       if(VIDEO != null && VIDEO.containsKey("tagLink")){
           VIDEO.getString("tagLink");

       }
   }


   public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! Errore di Connessione, provi a rientrare"+error.toString(),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   @Override
   public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
boolean wasRestored) {
          player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
   }
```

}

Comment: Can you clarify what's wrong? Conceptually, your code looks like it should work.

Comment: how do I insert multiple links to fill the listview

Comment: Maybe you can try adding a few more putExtra or just pass an array through putExtra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy. You have almost everything.

First to do is to pass the link in the intent by loading a listview with several links you need and an ArrayAdapter:

```
ListView mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mlist);

    String[] labels = new String[] { "name 1", "name 2", "name 3"};
    final String[] links = new String[] { "http://youtube.com/1", "http://youtube.com/2", "http://youtube.com/3"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, labels);
    mList.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter);
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(LocalActivity.this, DestinyActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("tagLink", links[position]);
            startActivity(mIntent);

        }
    });
```

And then, is to read in the DestinyActivity is to use a bundle in onCreate method:

```
Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(mBundle != null && mBundle.containsKey("tagLink")){
            VIDEO = mBundle.getString("tagLink");
        }
```

Use your (private String VIDEO) To past the value.

Comment: I tried in this way but in the listview I show now the link

Comment: Yes thats correct If you want To show some text in the listview and occult the link what you can do is create two arrays with the same dimension, one is the list label and the other is the link. 
If you want something more professional you can create you own adapter. You can see a tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Just change it with two arrays, one is the labels and the other is the links.

Comment: ok thanks, last question, in my activity where it is shown the video I have the following code's line private String VIDEO = "???"; quotation marks must insert ourselves mBundle? or should I just remove the quotes?

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question, but to get the string from the bundle is just String VIDEO = Bundle.getString("tagLink");

Comment: I edited my question can you help me figure out where mistake because as soon as I click on listview crashes. PLEASE

Comment: Don't Forget to check the manifest file and add the new activity or  else it will crush ... <activity
            android:name=".DestinyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             />

Comment: the manifest it's ok, then I have to send email with my activity?

Comment: ok I solved the crash, however, does not make me see the video,tells me there is an error with the network, 
But if I try to insert a manual link in the last activity video works

Comment: Your VIDEO can't be the bundle and the String ... change for this Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
       if(mBundle!= null && mBundle.containsKey("tagLink")){
           VIDEO = mBundle.getString("tagLink");

       }